# Pourquoi écrit-on calamar, calmar

Tags: prononciation, étymologie, orthographe

Pourquoi les mots "calamar" et "calmar" s'écrivent-ils différemment alors qu'ils se prononcent de la même manière ?
Ce que je dis est faux, alors ne le prenez pas en compte.

Comment: Où as-tu vu qu'ils se prononcent de la même façon ?

Answer (score 4):

- [Calmar](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/calmar) se prononce  [kalma:ʀ]
- [Calamar](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/calamar) se prononce [ka.la.maʁ] (introuvable dans le TLFi)

Comment: calmar, au sens de seiche https://www.larousse.fr/encyclopedie/divers/calmar/29997#:~:text=Mollusque%20c%C3%A9phalopode%20comestible%2C%20de%20forme,%2C%20Alloteuthis%2C%20Histioteuthis%2C%20etc.

Comment: @Emma Le calamar  [kalamaʁ] et le calmar [kalmaʁ], prononciations différentes, sont des noms pour un même [mollusque](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calmar). La seiche est aussi un mollusque mais un calamar n'est pas une seiche. Et selon les régions le calamar est aussi appelé chipiron ou encornet mais jamais sèche.

Answer (score 3):

*Pourquoi s'écrivent-ils différemment ?*

Parce que le premier est resté proche du latin *calamarus* ou de l'italien *calamaro* alors que le deuxième a suivi la prononciation plus courante *calmar*, peut-être par l'amuïssement du *E* dans la variante *calemar*.

[image]